# Symbolic math in sage: (a * x * y + z).subs(x + y == b)

Tags: math, substitution, symbolic-math, sage

Given a simple term `a * x * y + b`, I would like to substitute sub-terms, such as `x * y` by a placeholder `c`. I do this the following way

```
sage: a,b,c,x,y = var('a,b,c,x,y')
sage: expr = a * x * y + c
sage: expr.subs(x * y == b)
```

From that, I would expect `expr` to be `a * b + c`. Instead, it remains
the same. The result is:

```
a*x*y + c
```

I've come across the `wild` function, but it has not become clear to me
what it actually does.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I now use sympy in Python 3.6 rather than Sage, but this should be similar. Let me know if the translation to Sage doesn't work well.

The `subs` method does not change its object; it returns the expression after substitution, but you have to store the result. Your line `expr.subs(x * y == b)` may show the result but that result is then thrown away since you did not store it into any variable.

```
from sympy import symbols
a,b,c,x,y = symbols('a,b,c,x,y')
expr = a * x * y + c
newexpr = expr.subs(x*y, b)
print(newexpr)
```

The resulting printout is as you expect:

```
a*b + c
```

For confirmation of how `subs()` works in Sage, find `subs(` in [this Sage documentation page](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/polynomial_rings/sage/rings/polynomial/multi_polynomial_element.html) and note the phrase "The polynomial itself is not affected."

Comment: Thanks. Is 'sympy' comparable in its features? Can it compute a derivative, solve equations, etc.?

Comment: Assigning to a new expression does not solve the problem.

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer: Yes, sympy can do all those things. You probably know that William Stein, the inventor of Sage Math, has declared that Sage is dead. I started learning Sage but when I learned that fact I switched to Python. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SageMath) states that Sage uses sympy and Maxima to do calculus. I am sure Sage can do things that sympy cannot, but there almost certainly are other Python packages to do whatever that thing is.

Comment: @Frank-ReneSchäfer: Perhaps I should rephrase [what William Stein said](http://sagemath.blogspot.com/2014/08/what-is-sagemathcloud-lets-clear-some.html): "Sage is Failing" and "Measured by the mission statement, Sage has overall failed." He has moved to [CoCalc](https://cocalc.com/), which used to be called SageMathCloud.

Comment: Perhaps one should also mention that those are fairly old posts, and that his measure of whether Sage has failed is whether it is a competitor to Magma on certain number-theoretic computations that the vast majority of Sage users have no interest in.  Also, sympy is included in Sage!  So some users will use Sage to connect more directly to other included functionality, while others will wish to use a component such as sympy directly for convenience.